# How can I start a ViewController from within a Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to use the [TGCameraViewController](https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController) from within a iOS Cordova Plugin method.

Here is the implementation of the method:

```
#import "BCamera.h"
#import "TGCameraViewController.h"

@implementation BCamera

// Cordova command method
-(void) openCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

// take a photo

}
```

From the documentation of the TGCameraViewController I have to use the following to take a photo:

```
#import "TGCameraViewController.h"

@interface TGViewController : UIViewController <TGCameraDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoView;

- (IBAction)takePhotoTapped;

@end



@implementation TGViewController

- (IBAction)takePhotoTapped
{
    TGCameraNavigationController *navigationController =
    [TGCameraNavigationController newWithCameraDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - TGCameraDelegate optional

- (void)cameraWillTakePhoto
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)cameraDidSavePhotoAtPath:(NSURL *)assetURL
{
    // When this method is implemented, an image will be saved on the user's device
    NSLog(@"%s album path: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, assetURL);
}

- (void)cameraDidSavePhotoWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}

#pragma mark - TGCameraDelegate required

- (void)cameraDidTakePhoto:(UIImage *)image
{
    _photoView.image = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)cameraDidCancel
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

**How do I use this example to open the camera view from within my openCamera method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should present `TGCameraNavigationController` on rootViewController of your application, e.g.

```
@interface BCamera() <TGCameraDelegate>

@end

@implementation BCamera

- (void)openCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *) command
{    
    TGCameraNavigationController *navigationController = [TGCameraNavigationController newWithCameraDelegate:self];    
    UIViewController *rootVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [rootVC presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also you must implement `TGCameraDelegate` protocol methods.

```
- (void)cameraDidTakePhoto:(UIImage *)image
{
    //do something with image

    [self dismissCameraVC];
}

- (void)cameraDidCancel
{
    [self dismissCameraVC];
} 
- (void)dismissCameraVC
{
    UIViewController *rootVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];    
    [rootVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It is important that the Cordova Webview does not reset while the camera is open. Did you had this in mind?

Comment: It depends how Cordova Webview implemened. 
Just try it :)

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry for the question but could you please add to your answer how I know when the photo has been taken and how I get the photo and close the camera view?

Comment: May be you can help me with this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203643/how-cam-i-make-the-camera-view-to-open-faster

Comment: You don't really need to get the rootViewController, CDVPlugin already provides it with self.viewController