# How can I make the Camera View to open faster?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera

I use the iOS CameraViewController [TGCameraViewController](https://github.com/tdginternet/TGCameraViewController). It works great. My problem is that the camera view (i.e., when you run the example and hit the "capture image" button) view takes a very long time to be initialized and ready for the user. The AVFoundation is used.

**Is there a way to make the camera view appear much faster in the state where the user can capture a photo?**

**Edit:**

I initialized the ViewController right before I need it. The controller is called by a Cordova method call as follows:

```
-(void) openCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

  TGCameraNavigationController *navigationController = [TGCameraNavigationController  newWithCameraDelegate:self];    
  UIViewController *rootVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]  rootViewController];
  [rootVC presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Edit:

Here is what I did:

```
// Cordova command method
-(void) init:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

    [TGCamera setOption:kTGCameraOptionSaveImageToAlbum value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    _navigationController = [TGCameraNavigationController newWithCameraDelegate:self];
    _rootVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
}

// Cordova command method
-(void) openCamera:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {

    [_rootVC presentViewController: _navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I set up a part of the ViewController in an init method which is called only once when the app starts. Then when the user clicks on the take photo button in call openCamera. The problem is that this does not speed up the launch.

I tried the sample app from TGCameraViewController on iPhone5 and it takes a bit longer than the native camera app. This is exactly the problem I want the sample app to be as fast as the native camera app.

**Is there a better way to speed up the launch of the camera?**

Comment: Preload it at an earlier time?

Comment: @HAS What do you mean by that?

Comment: I guess you alloc/init the controller just before you show it. You could alloc/init at an earlier stage in your program flow and present the view controller when you actually need it.

Comment: @HAS I posted the code which opens the Camera. You are write. Could you post some code how I could do the init in a separate method before and then call openCamera whenever I want?

Comment: Hold TGCameraNavigationController's instance with strong pointer (say `@property (strong, nonatomic) TGCameraNavigationController *cameraNavigationController;` ) and allocate it in init method of your class. And then pass `self.cameraNavigationController` to `presentViewController:animated:complition` method.

Comment: @arturdev Please have a look at my edit. I tried a bit but does not change anything.

Comment: Check also viewWillDisappear: method of currently visible view controller.

Comment: Thanks @arturdev ... I was on mobile and couldn't post for whatever reason ... It might not work though since `TGCameraNavigationController` might make use of lazy loading. You would then need to actually load the view to initialize everything.

Comment: @HAS Could you please post some code example of what you mean?

Comment: @HAS I tried the sample app from TGCameraViewController on iPhone5 and as you said it takes a bit longer than the native camera app. This is exactly the problem I want the sample app to be as fast as the native camera app.

Comment: @HAS Isn't there a way to preload the camera and only showning it when I call openCamera?

Comment: @HAS No this is not the problem. I just talk about the sample app. When you click on "take photo" it feels so slow compared to the native camera app. Isn't there a way to make this faster?